# Get all Vector3-type variables (struct) and enumerate them from the whole code

Tags: c#, vector, struct

Firstly, this is just my "learning" of C# so it is not homework or something like that (I had a problems with that here, but I am just a "fanatic"). I am trying to get all values of Vector3 type (struct). I need to use something like this in my code:

```
foreach (Vector3 vector in Vector3.GetVector3List()) //maybe Vector3.GetVector3List<Vector3>()
{
    Console.WriteLine(vector);          
}
```

It should write all Vectors defined by user in Console.

Definition of my struct (simplified):

```
struct Vector3
{
    private double x, y, z;

    public double X
    {
        get { return x; }
        set { x = value; }
    }

    public double Y
    {
        get { return y; }
        set { y = value; }
    }

    public double Z
    {
        get { return z; }
        set { z = value; }
    }
    public Vector3(double x, double y, double z) : this()
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }
}
```

I am not sure in which way I should continue. I have tried 'enum-like' Getvalues function but logically it can't list all vectors as they are not defined until user doesn't do it in console.

```
private static List<T> GetVector3List<T>()
{
    //T[] array = (T[]) Vector3.GetValues(typeof (T));
}
```

One way is to store all entered vectors in List for example and then WriteLine them but I want to do it in the other way. Can somebody give me an advice how should I continue? (or if it is possible to get all Vectors just from struct)

Comment: What do you mean "get all vectors just from struct"? The Vector IS a struct.

Comment: Get all vector-type variables with function defined in struct of Vector3. So it puts/collects "together" all Vectors defined in the whole code and then I will be able to enumerate them (foreach...)

Comment: As in, enumerate every Vector3 found in every instance of every class in memory?

Comment: Yes. (Edited first comment)

Comment: Uhh.. you might want to rethink what you are trying to do. @romkyns Lol

Comment: Yes. I am not sure what I am trying to do I am in c# for a short time. I know it should be a problem (surely it is the worst method) but can it be done?

Comment: Just for s***s and giggles: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302542/how-do-i-get-all-instances-of-all-loaded-types-that-implement-a-given-interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no facility in .NET to enumerate all instances of a class. What's worse, you chose to make it a `struct`, which makes this even more impossible as there may be values of struct types on the stack, and strictly speaking the enumeration process itself produces new ones.

If you make `Vector3` a `class`, then you could theoretically keep track of them by recording creation in the constructor, but it's non-trivial in many ways. For starters, you had better use weak references...

Strictly speaking, there are debugging APIs that make this possible, but they are not trivial to use, and I'm not sure a program can use them on itself.

A bonus article on why [retrieving all instances of a type is a bad idea](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/12/10049155.aspx).

Comment: TL;DR; Don't try to do this.

Comment: Agreed, but if the OP is genuinely just curious then it's a fair question (although could have been phrased much more concisely)...

Comment: @mclaassen I am sorry for duplicate but I don't know why are you so "repulsive". I am just starting...everyone was..
Thank you, i was just curious about this

Comment: @Razzor too many people here ask questions because they want to code something weird, and other people then have to be paid to clean it up... so if you have any more "just out of curiosity" questions, make it clearer in the question. And maybe also try to make the question shorter. Most of your code samples were not really relevant to the question.

Comment: I thought that the code will be needed...I didn't know how to formulate a question but you are right in this. Next I am sorry

Comment: @Razzor I don't mean to be harsh, it's just rather shocking and humorous from the perspective of a more experienced developer to see someone trying to do something so strange.

Comment: @Razzor Don't worry about it. You'll find that this site can be a bit hostile when you don't know exactly what you want or can't explain it very clearly... but you'll probably get an answer one way or another anyway :)