# Loop for all objects of class without List/Array

Tags: c#, class, loops, object, foreach

It's possible to obtain a collection of all objects of certain class?

Given some arbitrary class, for example:

```
public class MyClass {
   public int anyVal;
   /* ...etc ... */
}
```

Is it possible to obtain a collection of all objects of certain class so you can iterate through them, like perhaps:

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
obj.anyVal = 333;

MyClass[] allObjects = //???              // <== HERE

foreach (MyClass mObj in allObjects) {
    Console.WriteLine("obj = " + mObj.anyVal);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Iterate through Class properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151888/c-sharp-iterate-through-class-properties)

Comment: @fubo i think the question is about instances of a class, but not about encapsulated objects.

Comment: Do you mean iterating over all the properties? It's really unclear what you're trying to do at the moment.

Comment: @fubo User does not asks how to iterate over <b>properties</b> of an instance.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?? Don't "fix" design flaws with reflection mess.

Comment: @XXXYYY what you mean by *all objects of class without List/Array* ? where are they stored ?

Comment: Okay, I add more details

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get all instances of all loaded types that implement a given interface?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302542/how-do-i-get-all-instances-of-all-loaded-types-that-implement-a-given-interface)

Answer (score 0):

No. You'd have to examine the Heap somehow and check the type for every object there. Not something you want to be doing.