# using typeof() to search for all object

Tags: c#, typeof, gettype

```
public class ClassA
{
   int num = 10;
}

ClassA a = new ClassA();
ClassA b = new ClassA();
ClassA c = new ClassA();
a.GetType(); //we can get result "ClassA"
```

Here is my question. Is that anyway I can get all Object of ClassA by using typeof(ClassA)? Or is that any other way? Thanks for your kind help

Comment: What do you mean by "all object"? Do you want to acces the `num`-field? You´ll need reflection in this case, something like `a.GetType().GetField("num")`.

Comment: Are you trying to get all _current instances_ of a certain type, in this case `ClassA`? Because you [won't be able to do that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302542/how-do-i-get-all-instances-of-all-loaded-types-that-implement-a-given-interface)

Comment: What is your real requirement? This reflection approach seems to be the last way you should take into consideration. Why don't you store the nums in a `List<int>` or the instances in a `List<ClassA>` ?

Comment: "get"? Get from where? It sounds like you may be after [Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt656691.aspx).

Comment: Sounds like xy-problem (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please describe your *actual* problem, not the way you think it should be solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to

> get all Object of ClassA

you may want to organize the `ClassA` instances into a *collection*, say, array and then use *Linq*:

```
Object[] source = new Object[] {
  "String",
  new ClassA(), // this 
  new Object(),
  new ClassA(), // and this should be filtered out
  null
};

...

ClassA[] result = source
  .OfType<ClassA>()
  .Where(item => item != null) // you may want this filter
  .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get all instances of a class that exist in your method, thread or whatever, you have to remember them on your own. However there is not a real need for this.

Imagine you have four different cars:

```
Car c1 = new Car();
Car c2 = new Car();
Car c3 = new Car();
Car c4 = new Car();
```

Now you have to options: either remember the variables names and try to get the car they represent by that name (which isn´t possible as you will find out soon) or put all your `Car`-instances into a single collection:

```
List<Car> cars = new List<Car>();
cars.Add(c1);
cars.Add(c2);
cars.Add(c3);
cars.Add(c4);
```

Now you won´t care for the names of those variables as you have direct access to them. You can access them by this for example:

```
Car myCar = cars.Single(x => x.Name == "BMW");
```

Or alternativly:

```
Car myCar = cars[1]; // get the second car within the collection
```

Answer (score -2):

C# has no API to retrieve all objects. Therefore, you have to write your own code.

```
public class ClassA
{
    int num = 10;

    public static List<ClassA> Objects { get; } = new List<ClassA>();
    public ClassA()
    {
        objects.Add(this);
    }
}
```

Use a static list to store the created objects.

```
ClassA a = new ClassA();
ClassA b = new ClassA();
ClassA c = new ClassA();

Console.WriteLine(ClassA.Objects[0]); //a
Console.WriteLine(ClassA.Objects[1]); //b
Console.WriteLine(ClassA.Objects[2]); //c
```

Be careful of memory leakage and remove objects from list as soon as used.

Comment: This is a very bad idea, since the objects will never be finalized (memory leak). It should be WeakReference at the very least.

Comment: You have to consider when Davis does retrieve those objects. If you use WeakReference inconsiderately, you end up with objects being accidentally destroyed.